# Как можно нажать на ссылку при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Как автоматически нажать на это при загрузке страницы?:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" id="contactbtn" href="#chatlist" role="button" aria-controls="chatlist">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

function ready() {
    document.getElementById('contactbtn').click();        
}
```